# EFCore 1.1 Scaffold-DbContext provider error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I can't get `Scaffold-DbContext` to work on a EFCore 1.1 application.

> PM> Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "'Server=.;Database=testsite;User Id=sa;Password=Password1234;'" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir EFContext -Context ApplicationDbContext

This is the error that it's giving:

> Scaffold-DbContext : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Scaffold-DbContext
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Scaffold-DbContext], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Scaffold-DbContext

Not exactly a forthcoming error message so I ran just `Scaffold-DbContext` and it gives me this error after prompting for the Provider.  The provider I'm trying to use is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I fixed it installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. Make sure to close and reopen VisualStudio. (Do not forget to add the -force flag to the end in order to reapply the changes from scratch)
Example:

> Scaffold-DbContext
>   "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;"
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -force

So, my dependencies looks like:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

After that it worked as expected.

Comment: Looking back on that old project I did have the Tools package installed.  In the end we just shelved .NET Core until 2.0 was released and whatever was broken in 1.1 just started working.

Marking this as the answer as it works correctly in 2.1 with this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple project in your solution you can try to add the option 
-StartupProject "nameofyourprojectstartup" with the project name that have to run this command.

I had the same error when trying to run "add-migration" with multiple project (Docker support) in my solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I had to do. Setting `Default Project` isn't enough, but adding that option will cause it to generate correctly!